# Where/How do you search for information on the Internet?

Tags: internet, search

Google Search or Search Engine wins; no contest.

What I want is the specialist content in websites dedicated to something.
The site where you go to search the specific information you want.

**Say: You woke up today and wanted to know about Household Appliances or Women Shoes or just any stuff you have no idea about, and you want to know all there is worth knowing.**

Examples : 
1.[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)([SF](https://serverfault.com/),[SU](http://superuser.com)) -- Programming 
2.[Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/)    -- All kinds of tips and tricks about software and poweruser stuff 
3.[Joelonsoftware](http://joelonsoftware.com/)-- Developer and Entrepreneurship 
4.[ReadWriteWeb](http://www.readwriteweb.com/)  -- Web Appl and Social Media 
5.[Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/)  -- General Information 
6.[Twitter](https://twitter.com/) -- Real Time Search

Answers : Either give many sites in one specialist category or different answers for different categories.

**Steps you go about researching a topic:  Say google it, Wikipedia search, then do a blog search, then twitter search, etc.**

**Okay No Movies or fun stuff, just programming or news or "serious stuff"**

It's a wiki. Feel free to reveal your secret methods of hunting stuff or those niche sites you get valuable info from.

Comment: This should be a wiki.

Comment: I am going to say this is wiki material.

Comment: Anyone else feel this is too broad to be a question? This would be better if it was limited to a topic or subset. This could go on for 100 pages.

Comment: @Troggy:  Broad, yes, but it is a good question.  Basically, which sites are the most popular "pointers to knowledge", broad or deep.

Answer (score 5):

Programming, I use google:

```
site:stackoverflow.com inurl:questions php
```

For old messages from friends on Twitter, I use google (google keeps cache'd messages):

```
site:twitter.com jonathansampson php
```

The same rule applies for nearly everything I search for outside of the biographical area, where I would use Wikipedia for obvious reasons

Answer (score 4):

- [Wikipedia.org](http://wikipedia.org/) - General information

Answer (score 4):

I use Google to search [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com) anytime I'm looking for a piece of desktop software to do... whatever.

I've created a keyword search bookmark for site:lifehacker.com, so I can just type "lh -keyword-" to search.

Comment: That works only 70% of the time , rest of the time??

Answer (score 3):

- [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) - For SQL, HTML and other scripting type stuff.  Great reference for simple stuff.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite site for consumer product research: [ConsumerReports.org](http://www.consumerreports.org).

**I check ConsumerReports.org any time I am interested in buying something for the household,** except for IT-related items.  ConsumerReports.org is the web site companion for the Consumer Reports magazine published by Consumers Union, and they have an archive of the ratings published in the magazine, plus additional content and user forums.  Whether you are buying a dishwasher, BBQ, automobile, lawn mower, etc. chances are good that you will find some useful information on which models measure up, and which to avoid.

Caveat: Their site is subscription-based.  But, I understand they need subscription revenue since they *don't accept ads*, as that could compromise their independence.  Nevertheless, **US$26/yr** or **US$19/yr if you subscribe to the magazine** are great deals.

Final interesting tidbit:  Consumers Union recently bought [The Consumerist](http://www.consumerist.com) blog/web site, also a worthy resource for consumerrs.

Answer (score 2):

I just google for anything, refining the search depending on the search results I get.

Answer (score 1):

> ### [Twitter](http://twitter.com)

for up-to-date news and instant information

Comment: Twitter is an important tool for real time search!!!

Comment: yes it is, seriously can't understand why the down vote is for??

Comment: Dont worry ,I gave you an upvote , start revising your answer to contain all the ways you use to search on the internet

Comment: obviously he didn't mention is "search" is about programming or not, anyways twitter can be used for anything I guess http://twitter.com/#search?q=superuser.com ;)

Comment: Read the Edited Question , i have revised it and phrased it properly

Answer (score 1):

For buying computer parts, especially for building a PC, I use a combination of Wikipedia (specifications, model #'s, cross-reference lists) and Newegg (to get the best deals, reviews) and Amazon (mainly for comparitive reviews if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

For programming, my first point of research is always the documentation. PHP and Java have excellent docs.

For general stuff, I'll use google to site: search (mostly SO, SF, SU). Just knowing how to use google properly, though, beats everything else.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) for MS related documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [AllTop](http://alltop.com/).  I know of it; I don't really use it - I find Google better for my purposes.  And so far, neither Bing nor Wolfram Alpha has provided me with better answers than Google for the questions I've wanted answers to.  I guess I don't ask the same questions as the general population - which doesn't surprise me too much.